# Conditional distribution problem

Tags: calculus, probability

Given random variables X and Y with joint density

$$f(x,y) = 2(x + y), \text{ for } 0 < y < x < 1,$$

I am trying to compute the probability that

$$P(Y < 0.5 \mid X = 0.1)$$

To that end, I computed the marginal density

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^x 2(x + y) \, \mathrm d{y} \\
         = 3x^2 
$$

We now have enough information to compute the conditional distribution

$$f(y|x) = \frac{2(x + y)}{3x^2}$$

and, fixing the condition,

$$f(y|x = 0.1) = \frac{0.2 + y}{3(0.1)^2}$$

Finally, to compute the probability, we find the conditional distribution

$$F(y \mid X=0.1)    = \frac{1}{3(0.1)^2} \int_0^y 0.2  + 2y \, \mathrm d{y} \\
                  = \frac{1}{3(0.1)^2}          0.2y + y^2$$

and substitute

$$F(0.05 \mid X=0.1) = \frac{1}{3(0.1)^2}          0.1 + (0.05)^2$$

Plugging these into a calculator yields approximately 4.17, instead of 0.417, which my solution sheet says is the answer.  Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your work is correct (ignoring a few typos); it's just a calculator error. Plugging in $y=0.05$ yields:
$$
F(0.05 | X=0.1) = \dfrac{1}{3(0.1)^2} (0.2(0.05) + (0.05)^2) = 0.41666...
$$